# Image doesn't transfer filter (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am using Xcode to build an Instagram app.

In my project, I applied a filter to an image, but when I send it to the database and retrieve it in another view, the filter is not showing up.

[image]

This is after applying the filter, and it shows up without the filter in home view:

[image]

**Filter View Code :**

```
//
//  FillterVC.swift
//  InstaPJT1
//
//  Created by MacBook Pro on 06/11/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 MacBook Pro. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol FillterVCDelegate {
    func transformPhotoToCamera (image : UIImage)
}

class FillterVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagePostOUtLet: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOUtLet: UICollectionView!

    var delegate : FillterVCDelegate?

    var selectedImage : UIImage!
    var filters = [
        "CIPhotoEffectChrome",
        "CIPhotoEffectFade",
        "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
        "CIPhotoEffectNoir",
        "CIPhotoEffectProcess",
        "CIPhotoEffectTonal",
        "CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
        "CISepiaTone"
        ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imagePostOUtLet.image = selectedImage
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate?.transformPhotoToCamera(image: imagePostOUtLet.image!)
    }

    func resizeImageScale (image : UIImage , newWidth : CGFloat)-> UIImage {
        let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
        let newHeigh = image.size.height * scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth , height: newHeigh))
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeigh))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }

}

extension FillterVC : UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filters.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FillterCell", for: indexPath) as! FillterCell
        let newImage = resizeImageScale(image: selectedImage, newWidth: 200)
        print(selectedImage.size)
        print(newImage.size)
        let ciImage = CIImage(image: newImage)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: filters[indexPath.item])
        filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        if let filterdImage = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage? {
             cell.filteredImageOutLet.image = UIImage(ciImage: filterdImage)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let ciImage = CIImage(image: selectedImage)

               let filter = CIFilter(name: filters[indexPath.item])
               filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
               if let filterdImage = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage? {
                    imagePostOUtLet.image = UIImage(ciImage: filterdImage)
               }

    }

}
```

**Camera View:**

```
//
//  CameraVC.swift
//  InstaPJT1
//
//  Created by MacBook Pro on 22/01/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 MacBook Pro. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD
import AVFoundation

class CameraVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var reomveButtonLabel: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var captionTextVIew: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!

    var selectedPhotoToDataBase : UIImage?
    var selectedVidoeToDataBase : URL?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGuster = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CameraVC.handelPhtotSelected))
        photo.addGestureRecognizer(tapGuster)
        photo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        handelPostsEmpty()
    }

    @objc func handelPostsEmpty () {
//        if selectedPhotoToDataBase != nil {
//            shareButton.isEnabled = true
//            reomveButtonLabel.isEnabled = true
//            shareButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
//        } else {
//            shareButton.isEnabled = false
//            reomveButtonLabel.isEnabled = false
//            shareButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
//            
//
//        }
    }

    @objc func handelPhtotSelected () {
        print("user try to tap on photo")
        let photoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        photoPicker.delegate = self
        photoPicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image","public.movie"]
        present(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func share_onTouch(_ sender: Any) {
       // view.endEditing(true)
        print("ndndndndnd")
        if let profileIMG = self.selectedPhotoToDataBase , let imageData = profileIMG.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            let ratio = profileIMG.size.width / profileIMG.size.height
            print("image size = \(ratio)")
            HelperService.UploadDataToStorage(vidoeURL : selectedVidoeToDataBase , imageData: imageData, ratio : ratio , captionTextVIew: captionTextVIew.text
                , OnSuccess: {
                    SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "تم النشر بنجاح")
                    self.Clean()

            }) { (error) in
                SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func Clean () {
        self.captionTextVIew.text = ""
        self.photo.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder-photo")
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0 // بعد ما ينحفظ البوست راح ترجع بنا الصفحة الى الصفحة الرئيسية
        self.selectedPhotoToDataBase = nil
    }

    @IBAction func removeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.captionTextVIew.text = ""
        self.photo.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder-photo")
        self.selectedPhotoToDataBase = nil
        SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "Removed")
        handelPostsEmpty()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Fillter_Segue" {
            let fitlervc = segue.destination as! FillterVC
            fitlervc.selectedImage = selectedPhotoToDataBase
            fitlervc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

extension CameraVC : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
// Local variable inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

        print(info)
        if let vidoeURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] as? URL {
            if let thumbnailForVidoe = self.thubmnailImageForFileURL(vidoeURL) {
                photo.image = thumbnailForVidoe
                selectedPhotoToDataBase = thumbnailForVidoe

                selectedVidoeToDataBase = vidoeURL

            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        if let photoSelectedFromLibriry = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage {
            photo.image = photoSelectedFromLibriry
            selectedPhotoToDataBase = photoSelectedFromLibriry
            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Fillter_Segue", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func thubmnailImageForFileURL (_ file : URL) -> UIImage? {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: file)
        let imageGenenartor = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

        do {
           let thumbImage = try   imageGenenartor.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 7, timescale: 4), actualTime: nil)
            return UIImage(cgImage: thumbImage)

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        return UIImage()
    }

}

// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
fileprivate func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(_ input: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map {key, value in (key.rawValue, value)})
}

// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
fileprivate func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_ input: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey) -> String {
    return input.rawValue
}

extension CameraVC : FillterVCDelegate {
    func transformPhotoToCamera(image: UIImage) {
        self.photo.image = image
    }
}
```

**Home View :**

```
//
//  HomeVC.swift
//  InstaPJT1
//
//  Created by MacBook Pro on 22/01/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 MacBook Pro. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SVProgressHUD
import SDWebImage

class HomeVC: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewOutLet: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var postContentArray = [Post]() // contine all Posts .
    var userContentArray = [UserModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableViewOutLet.dataSource = self
        tableViewOutLet.delegate = self
        tableViewOutLet.estimatedRowHeight = 521
        tableViewOutLet.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        loadPosts()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }


    @objc func loadPosts () {
      //  activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
        API.Feed.ObserveFeedWithMyPostAndFollowerPost(withid: API.User.Curren_User!.uid) { (postr) in

            self.fetchUserInfo(PostUserID: postr.userPostId!, Completed: {
            self.postContentArray.append(postr)
          //  self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

            self.tableViewOutLet.reloadData()

                            })
        }

        API.Feed.ObserveFeedReomved(withid: API.User.Curren_User!.uid) { (post) in
            // print(key)

            // a لحذف منشورات المستخدم من التيبل فيو
       //   self.postContentArray.removeLast()
            self.postContentArray = self.postContentArray.filter {$0.postID !=  post.postID}
            self.userContentArray = self.userContentArray.filter {$0.id != post.userPostId}
            self.tableViewOutLet.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @objc func fetchUserInfo (PostUserID : String , Completed : @escaping ()-> Void) {

        API.User.observeUserInformation(CommentUserID: PostUserID) { (User) in
            self.userContentArray.append(User)
            Completed()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func logOutButton(_ sender: Any) {

        AuthServices.logout(OnSuccess: {
        SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "تم تسجيل الخروج")
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
            let signInvc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInVC")
            self.present(signInvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }) { (error) in
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "commentIconSequeToCommentPage" {
            let commentvc = segue.destination as! CommentsVC
            commentvc.postID = sender as? String
        }
        if segue.identifier == "Home_ToUserProfileTappedVC" {
            let userid = segue.destination as! UserProfileTappedVC
            userid.userID = sender as! String

        }
    }
}

extension HomeVC: UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postContentArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let postContent = postContentArray[indexPath.row]
        let userContent = userContentArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.postContent = postContent
        cell.userContentInfo = userContent
        // l لتفعيل زر الردود و مساواته بالمتغير هوم فيو الموجود في ملف هوم تيبل فيو سيل
        cell.homeView = self
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension HomeVC : HomeTableViewCellDelegate {
    func GoToUserProfileTappedVC(id: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home_ToUserProfileTappedVC", sender: id)
    }

    func GoToCommentVC(postID: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "commentIconSequeToCommentPage", sender: postID)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saying `imagePostOUtLet.image = UIImage(ciImage: filterdImage)`. So all you are doing is showing the filtered image in the interface. I don't see any point where you _save_ the filtered image into the database.

Comment: hi , after applying filter method  to image i implment segue to the camera view controller with filterd image and alos save to data base , but when i check the database saved image it dosn't show the fitlerd image . so i should save the image in ther filter view controller insted of save it in camer vc ?